# Trouble printing this f-string

Tags: python, f-string

I'm just trying this normal piece of code that has an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), but in the particular line mentioned below, I couldn't determine what's the problem:

```
elif(BMI<25):
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI),you have normal weight.")
```

Comment: `print(f"Your BMI is {BMI}, you have normal weight.")`

Comment: What was unclear about the error message `SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched ')'`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a `)` after the third "BMI", needs to be a `}`.

Comment: In cases like this, you ought to comment and then VTC as a typo.